# Akka-streams: execute action on flow start

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Having a flow description in *akka-streams*

```
val flow: Flow[Input, Output, Unit] = ???
```

, how do I modify it to get a new flow description that performs a specified side-affect on start, i.e. when flow is materialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting materialization of a stream processing graph will set it in motion piece by piece, concurrently. The only way to perform an action that is guaranteed to happen before the first element is passed somewhere within that graph is to perform that action before materializing the graph. In this sense the answer by sschaef is slightly incorrect: using `mapMaterializedValue` runs the action pretty early, but not such that it is guaranteed to happend before the first element is processed.

If we are talking about a `Flow` here which only takes in inputs on one side and produces outputs on the other—i.e. it does not contain internal cycles or data sources—then one thing you can do to perform an action before the first element arrives is to attach a processing step to its input that does that:

```
def effectSource[T](block: => Unit) = Source.fromIterator(() => {block; Iterator.empty})
val newFlow = Flow[Input].prepend(effectSource(/* do stuff */)).via(flow)
```

---

***Note***

The above is using upcoming 2.0 syntax, in Akka Streams 1.0 it would be `Source(() => { block; Iterator.empty })` and the prepend operation would need to be done using the FlowGraph DSL (the graph can be found [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/a21d0592a7fb475d07752709b792e85c7ef56ed7/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L1458)).

Comment: Ronald, what if the effectful action is asynchronous? Couldn't find something like `def apply[T](f: () => Future[T])` on `Source` (since Scala's futures are not reusable).

Comment: There will shortly be `Source.unfoldAsync` (see [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/88d8fd1cf19004dc90bc31ef33010636ecd7d44e/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.scala#L267)).

Comment: Ronald, now looking at `unfoldAsync` and it looks cumbersome to use it. I just need to perform a side-effect and don't add anything to the stream, while `unfoldAsync` requires some initial value and a result of type `Future[Option[(S, E)]]`.

Answer (score 3):

You said it by yourself, use the force of the materialization:

```
val newFlow = flow.mapMaterializedValue(_ ⇒ println("materialized"))
```

Comment: Will `println` be invoked as the very first action of the flow before something really goes through it?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole concept of materialization. See: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M2/scala/stream-composition.html#materialized-values

Comment: Materialization sets the flow in motion without synchronization, though, meaning that the effect may well run concurrently to the flow.